# Android issue HorizontalPager + vertical scroll

Tags: android, slider, horizontal-scrolling, pager, vertical-scrolling

I've been looking for a horizontal pager class, capable of horizontally slide between views with a  vertical scroll. I first tried with the realviewswitcher, but it didn't slide horizontally if there was a vertical scroll in the view. Then I found this one:

https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

I have only 3 views un the HorizontalPager. In order to simulate an infinite number o views I do this so I can scroll indefinitely and add the content dinamically:

```
private final HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener =
        new HorizontalPager.OnScreenSwitchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenSwitched(final int screen) {
                // Check the appropriate button when the user swipes screens.
                if(screen==0)
                {;
                    if(index==0) index=num_pags-1;
                    else index--;
                }
                else if (screen==2)
                {
                    if(index==num_pags-1) index=0;
                    else index++;
                }
                mPager.setCurrentScreen(1, false);
            }
        };
```

Both scrolls work just fine, but suddenly it won't slide horizontally, after a while it stops sliding horizontally.

Comment: Found a modified class that does the trick for me. https://github.com/shilgapira/horizontalpager